# linq query convert text to date to compare with another date vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, linq

I have a database field, Field260, that stores date representations as text. For instance a value for 3/29/2018 would be stored as a string `"03/29/2018"`

```
 Dim Db = New DataClasses1DataContext

 Return From cf In Db.FileDatas
     Where cf.Field260 <= System.DateTime.Today
```

Returns error

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Explicit conversion from data type text to datetime is not allowed.'
```

When I tried to Parse the date

```
Where DateTime.Parse(cf.Field260) <= System.DateTime.Today
```

I receive

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'Method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.'
```

I'm stumped.

Comment: THANKS FOR THE DOWNVOTES!!! MORE PLEASE.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue - have an app that I used to have a DatePicker for a field, and my database field defined as DateTime, but the users absolutely wanted to copy/paste whatever garbage they wanted into the field. Problem is, I'm allowing them to search for records by that "Date" field.

As a workaround, I do some basic validations on the garbage they enter to attempt to only allow dates (IsDate function captures most errors, but still allows them to enter years like 208 instead of 2018, so I also check that Year(DateValue(txtDate.Text))>2000, which works for me because it's an application-received date, so should never be older than this year).  Then I store it as varchar in the database.

When searching for the records, you have two options - either grab all records, then perform a date conversion on the list returned to pare down the results, or hope and pray that your faulty LINQ WHERE clause will get everything you want.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out cuz I'm a genius.

```
 Return From cf In Db.FileDatas
     Where cf.Field260.ToString() <= System.DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Somehow comparing string to string works, who knew!

Comment: No; comparing strings isn't the same as comparing dates. For example the string "12/31/2017" will compare as greater than the string "01/01/2018". You should convert the string to a date before comparing, and you probably shouldn't be storing a date as a string in the database in the first place.

Comment: The best and most beautiful things in the world cannot be seen or even touched - they must be felt with the heart. - The Late Helen Keller

Comment: Every time you treat a date as a string, you make [a kitten sad](https://i.imgur.com/7Dup7Ve.jpg)

Comment: @Blackwood obviously I should use dates, but did you read my question? I'm getting errors when attempting the conversion. Perhaps you have some insight like @Plutonix?

Comment: I read your answer and tried to explain why it will not work in some cases.

Comment: I got that, but you got any insight to OP's question?